# Keeping even numbered elements of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an `$input` array, that contains something like this :

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  4 => string 'e' (length=1)
  5 => string 'f' (length=1)
  6 => string 'g' (length=1)
  7 => string 'h' (length=1)
  8 => string 'i' (length=1)
  9 => string 'j' (length=1)
```

I want to get an `$output` array, that would contain this :

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'c' (length=1)
  2 => string 'e' (length=1)
  3 => string 'g' (length=1)
  4 => string 'i' (length=1)
```

The `$output` array contains half the values that were in `$input` ; those that had even numbered keys in the input; the first one is kept, second one is not, third one is, and so one...

*(Note: the keys are not preserved ; only the values are important)*

**How could I do that ? Keeping only one on two values of the array ?**

---

I have already tried some ideas, and already have a couple different solutions :

**First idea:** iterate over the input array, and copy the interesting values to the output array:

```
$input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
$output = array();

$nbr = count($input);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nbr ; $i += 2) {
    $output[] = $input[$i];
}

var_dump(array_values($output));
```

**Second idea:** iterate over the array, and `unset` what I don't want to keep:

```
$input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
$output = $input;

$nbr = count($input);
for ($i = 1 ; $i < $nbr ; $i += 2) {
    unset($output[$i]);
}

var_dump(array_values($output));
```

**Third idea:** use a combinaison of `array_flip`, `range`, `array_diff_key`, ... :

```
$input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
$output = array();

$keys_to_exclude = array_flip(range(1, count($input)-1, 2));
$output = array_diff_key($input, $keys_to_exclude);

var_dump(array_values($output));
```

**Fourth idea:** about the same thing, but with `array_intersect_key`:

```
$input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
$output = array();

$keys_to_include = array_flip(range(0, count($input)-1, 2));
$output = array_intersect_key($input, $keys_to_include);

var_dump(array_values($output));
```

Any other idea ? Even / particularly if it sounds kinda hacky or anything ?

*My goal is not to get the most efficient nor simple syntax ; it's just for fun and because I am curious, actually ^^*

*If the title is not using the right words to describe what I want, don't hesitate to tell ; or edit it* **:-)**

Comment: I edited the title and description of the algorithm a little as requested.  Personally I'd use the first idea - it's simple and fairly clear what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the edits :-) Well, actually, "how can I do that whithout looping by myself" is a question that poped-up at work couple of days ago ; a colleague and I thought about it... and we finally used the "for" solution (the first one I gave) : less fun, but easier to understand when someone will have to maintain our code -- and that's one of the most important thing in our job ; but, it was still an interesting question, and I thought I might get some funny/interesting propositions here ^^

Comment: +1 for well-formulated question with own ideas

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = range('a', 'f');

$x = array_map('array_shift', 
       array_chunk($x, 2)
     );

var_dump($x);
```

or another one

```
<?php
class ArrayEvenIterator extends ArrayIterator {
    public function next() {
        parent::next();
        return parent::next();
    }
}

$x = range('a', 'f');
$x = iterator_to_array(new ArrayEvenIterator( $x ), false);

var_dump($x);
```

or with a php 5.3 closure (which isn't better than global in this case ;-) )

```
<?php
$x = range('a', 'f');

$x = array_filter( $x, function($e) use(&$c) { return 0===$c++%2; });

var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Nice ones too! thanks :-) didn't think about using a closure (my mind is not yet used to those in PHP, I guess ^^ (and I can't use PHP 5.3 as much as I'd like :-( ))

Comment: +1 for using closures and for the `iterator_to_array` (that I didn't know of).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming numeric keys:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 != 0) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here goes my slightly more insane solution which keeps the index continuous without re-indexing. ;o)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!($key%2)) {
        $array[$key/2] = $value;
    }
}
$array = array_slice($array, 0, ceil(count($array)/2));
```

Comment: @Pascal (OP): I have to admit this is not so terrifically different from your `for` solution, but I think you covered almost all bases already yourself. Most sane solutions should pretty much only differ in syntactic sugar. :)

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest as well. If keys are not numeric you could perhaps run the array through a function and create a new array of elements with numeric keys. Each element would then be an array of the key/value pair from the original array.

The nice thing about the Modulus operator is that it can be used to find all sorts of number of elements. To find every 5th element 
if ($key % 5 == 0)
This means divide by 5 and return remainder. A list 0 through 15 elements would return 0, 5, 10, and 15 each of which return a remainder of 0 when divided by 5. e.g 10/5 = 2 R0.

Comment: @deceze : yep, you're right, there is no "miracle" AND maintenable solution ^^ But that's were the fun is ;-) Thanks anyway, didn't think about the modulus!

Comment: Note that this version preserves the input keys (
    [0] => a
    [2] => c
    [4] => e
    [6] => g
    [8] => i
) , which might well be useful, but doesn't match the specified output.  Using array_values($array) on the output would achieve this of course.

Comment: I really don't care about the keys in this situation ; but that's good to know in case I need those some day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or later, or have the SPL extension installed (you will by default on PHP 5), you can use the [FilterIterator](http://php.net/filteriterator) and [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject) classes.

```
class EvenKeysFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private function iseven($keyval)
    {
        return (($keyval % 2) == 0);
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $keyval = $this->getInnerIterator()->key();
        return ($this->iseven($keyval));
    }
}

$input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
$inputobj = new ArrayObject($input);   

$evenFilterIter = new EvenKeysFilter($inputobj->getIterator());    
$output = iterator_to_array($evenFilterIter, false);

print_r($output);
```

(Props to [VolkerK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218591/keeping-even-numbered-elements-of-an-array/1218634#1218634) for pointing out [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/iterator-to-array))

Which correctly outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => c
    [2] => e
    [3] => g
    [4] => i
)
```

Comment: Don't know why, but I think I love this one ! Wouldn't probably use it in an application someone else will have to maintain, but I definitly like it (and didn't think about SPL). Thanks :-)  (just a '(' that has to be removed in the accept method, and then it works)

Comment: I agree, SPL is probably overkill for this case, but stuff like RecursiveIteratorIterator is invaluable.

Comment: It's just too bad that people (including myself, actually) generally don't use the SPL enough :-(

Comment: +1 for the cleverness use of SPL. I need to pay more attention to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most efficient method, but since you mentioned that wasn't necessarily a requirement...

flip, filter, then flip back.

```
<?php
    function even($var)
    {
        return(!($var & 1));
    }

    $input = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', );
    $flipped = array_flip($input);
    $filtered = array_filter($flipped, 'even');
    $output = array_flip($filtered);
?>
```

Comment: This might produce unexpected/unintuitive results depending on the input. E.g. $input = array('a', 'a', 'b'); -> $output==array('b')

Answer (score 0):

I would invert the bitwise-odd check and either use `array_filter()` (and reindexing the result with `array_values()`) or use a classic `foreach()` loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VnamK))

```
$array = range('a', 'j');
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_filter(
            $array,
            function($k) {
                return !($k & 1);
            },
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
        )
    )
);
echo "\n---\n";
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    if (!($index & 1)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'c',
  2 => 'e',
  3 => 'g',
  4 => 'i',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'c',
  2 => 'e',
  3 => 'g',
  4 => 'i',
)
```

In my own projects, I prefer to keep global variable declarations to a minimum, so I'd use `array_filter()`.

Answer (score -2):

create a wrapper function

```
function getInput($i)
{
     global $input;
     return $input[$i*2];
}
```

The smallest and most efficient I guess.

Comment: It certainly is small, but what's it do?

Answer (score -3):

```
  function dropHalf($a){
     $f=0;
     foreach($a as $k=>$v)
       if($f = ! $f)
         unset($a[$k]);
     return $a;
  }
```

That's the smallest version I could think off.

Comment: Aren't you missing something?